# Is USDT ERC20 token or omni?

Tags: erc-20

for USDT,

1. Is there any wallet or holding usdt coin? Is it is erc 20, what is the contract address? Which USDT popular, omni or erc20? these two equal?
2. Is there any USDT api to use? or USDT payment gateway?

Answer (score 4):

USDT has both an Omni and an [ERC20](https://tether.to/usd%E2%82%AE-and-eur%E2%82%AE-now-supported-on-ethereum/) implementation.

You can use the APIs of any exchange offering USDT trading for Omni or ERC20 to trade them.

Comment: thanks, is there any wallet I can hold the usdt? such as similiar to bitcoin core

Comment: thanks and good wallet to hold usdt? since i do not believe the exchangers